# why doesnot redirect/shows the view ? + laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, view

I am working in a import method, that save the data od an *.csv into a table, but i verify if this data already exist in table, if this is true, i would redirect to a view or to another method, but dont redirect!
In the line

> //comparing if the data of file exists in the table
>   if exists data i try to make a return:
>     return view ('catinvistas.ingresos.mensaje');
>   and must to finish all the following proccess, right?

```
    public function import()
    {

        Excel::load('storage\app\reloj.csv', function($reader) {

     foreach ($reader->get() as $marcacion) {
 //file data
        $archivo=(int)$marcacion->id_voluntario;
        $archivo_fecha=$marcacion->marcacion;

        //table data
        $tabla_c1 = DB::table('marcaciones')->where('id_voluntario', $marcacion->id_voluntario)->first();
     if (!empty($tabla_c1)){

              $tabla=(int)$tabla_c1->id_voluntario;
        $tabla_fecha=$tabla_c1->marcacion; 

        //comparing if the data of file exists in the table

     if (($tabla==$archivo) && ($tabla_fecha==$archivo_fecha))
         {
       //dd ($tabla,$tabla_fecha,$archivo,$archivo_fecha);
      return view ('catinvistas.ingresos.mensaje');

      }   
    }  
     //insert all data of the file into the table
     Marcaciones::create([
     'id_voluntario' =>$marcacion->id_voluntario,
     'marcacion' => $marcacion->marcacion   
     ]);        

       }         
 });

   $data=Marcaciones::all();     
   return view('catinvistas.ingresos.importacion')->with('data',$data); 
 }
```

Comment: Why should it redirect? You don't use redirect() anywhere, you are only returning views.

Comment: Yes. Because the view that it shows is. "Importacion" and i need to show the view "mensaje"

Comment: you should use `redirect()` instead of `view()`